# All non-duplicate combinations of two list elements

Tags: haskell

It's easier to explain this with an example:

I want to write a function [a] -> [(a,a)] so if I get a list

```
[A, B, C, D]
```

I want this list to return:

```
[(A, A), (A,B), (A,C), (A,D), (B,B), (B,C), (B,D), (C,C), (C,D), (D,D)]
```

I came up with this code:

```
function s = [(x,y) | x <- s, y <- s, x<=y]
```

Which works correctly for a list of integers, but I want this to work for data types that are not instances of the Ord class. My data type derives Show and Eq. So is there a simple way to solve this problem? I'm thinking maybe by filtering the tuples from

```
function s = [(x,y) | x <- s, y <- s]
```

But I dont know how I can do that either.

Comment: What is the output for `[A,A,A,A]`?

Comment: I think it's implied that the elements are unique (conceptually a set).

Answer (score 4):

Solution using recursion:

```
f :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
f []     = []
f (x:xs) = [(x, y) | y <- (x:xs)] ++ f xs
```

Without recursion:

```
import Data.List (tails) 

f' :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
f' xs = concat [[(head x, y) | y <- x] | x <- tails xs]
```

Without list comprehension:

```
import Data.List (tails) 

f'' :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
f'' xs = concatMap (\sl -> zip (repeat $ head sl) sl) (tails xs)
```

Best is by Daniel Wagner, just use

```
[(head x, y) | x <- tails xs, y <- x]
```

Comment: Why `concat` when you're already in a list comprehension? `f' xs = [(head x, y) | x <- tails xs, y <- x]`. And then the next obvious question is, why use `head` when pattern matching will do? `f' xs = [(h, y) | x@(h:_) <- tails xs, y <- x]`.

Comment: That would be better, agreed, although I think using `head` is fine.

Answer (score 2):

It's a nested loop.

```
import Data.List (dropWhile)

com xs = do
  x <- xs
  y <- dropWhile (/= x) xs
  return (x, y)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `scanr`

```
f l = zip l (scanr (:) [] l) >>= \(h,t) -> fmap ((,) h) t
```

First you get list of (heads, tails) of `l`, map tails pairing their elements with corresponding head and finally flatten everything.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing the idea of filter `[(x,y) | x <- xs, y <- xs]`, you could do it using foldl instead:

```
f = foldl add [] 
  where add ys (a,b) | notElem (b,a) ys = (a,b):ys 
                     | otherwise = ys

g xs = [(x,y) | x <- xs, y <- xs]

function = f . g
```